# Preventing a field from rendering on a page

Tags: theming, entities

How would I prevent `field_home_slider` from rendering when `$page['content']` is loaded? I only want it to load when I call it separately. I also still want the page content to be displayed just do not include the `field_home_slider`

Display image by itself

```
  if(isset($node->field_home_slider)){
     $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_home_slider');
     $bannerImage = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_home_slider', $field[0]);
     print render($bannerImage);
  }
```

and below to display content on the page

```
print render($page['content']);
```

Comment: Try to use view mode in this. Set a view mode in manage display and exclude that field which you dont want to render from this view mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to  Display management of your content type  in `admin/structure/types/manage/{yourcontenttypename}/display`  and  set `Formatter` as `Hidden`.

Also you can  hide it with [hide function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/hide/7)  before render it in `node template`.

```
  hide($content['field_home_slider']);
  print render($content);
```